# In elementor why responsive font size doesn't change?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive, font-size, elementor

I'm building a new website with elementor but during the editing I have some problem with switching in the responsive mobile mode from desktop mode.
When I switch in mobile mode I try to change the font size but it doesn't work, particularly I can change the value of the font size but it doesn't change in the preview and in frontend at all.
Also if I switch in responsive mobile mode and I apply some changes, some of these changes pass also in the desktop mode.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the changes you're trying to make for the mobile styling are being overruled by CSS styles coming from somewhere else. Some places you could check are

- look for inline CSS styles in the widget > content > text tab
- widget > advanced > custom CSS
- site settings ( click the hamburger icon at the top left of any elementor page)

If you still don't have any success, there's nothing to stop you from creating some custom CSS for the widget and using an @media() rule to target mobile devices.